# Python Invalid Syntax in subprocess.check_output

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, subprocess

I have trouble when passing this input as parameter to this function

the input:

```
command = (
                f"'{self.script_dir + 'data.sh'}' "
                f"-D '{self.data_dir}' "
                f"-T '{self.tfds_dir}' "
                f"-R '{self.records_dir}' "
                f"-j {data_url} " 
                f"-a {annotations_url} "
                f"-m {detections_url} "
                f"-I '{self.params['img_dir']}' "
                f"-r {self.params['use_records']} "
                f"-d {self.params['dataset']} "
                f"-i {self.params['download_images']} "
            ),
            message='Data files downloaded.\n'
```

the function:

```
def call_bash(command, message=None):
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(
            command, 
            shell=True, 
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        )
        if message is not None:
            print(message) 
        return output
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(e.output)
        print("Exiting program...")
        sys.exit()
```

It ran just fine on colab, but when I run the program in jupyter notebook, I got this syntax error:

```
f"'{self.script_dir + 'data.sh'}' "
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: add commas? what exactly do you want it to do?

Comment: If Jupyter is running Python <= 3.5 then that is why an `f`-string is giving a syntax error.

Comment: no, the jupyter is running on 3.6.9 and This command supposed to check the content of some parameter and directory

Comment: that input and function actually not directly write in a cell, they were called from a .py script using !python

Comment: @drum: You don't need to add commas; adjacent string literals (including f-string literals) concatenate. The parentheses are needed to keep them adjacent, the OP isn't trying to make a `tuple`, they're just trying to define a long f-string literal across multiple lines to keep their line lengths reasonable and the contents readable. Adding commas would make it a `tuple` of many small strings, rather than one large string.